# Symfony2 : error 403 and 404 on prod envrionment

Tags: php, symfony

I am facing an issue with Symfony2. I have created a website, it works fine locally.
I can access localhost/symfony/web to see my site on prod. (it doesn't work if I go to app.php, I get redirected to the wamp index page, but it seems to be normal on the Symfony version I use - 2.2.1 )

Online I have a 404 error when I try to access http://www.mywebsite.com/web
If I try to go to any other page (like www.mywebsite.com), I get a 403 error.
But I can go to http://www.mywebsite.com/web/app_dev.php or http://www.mywebsite.com/web/config.php without error.

I am using a shared server (1&1 starter).
I don't see anything in the logs. I have cleared the caches (both dev and prod), but it doesn't change anything.

I am lost... can anyone help me?
Thanks,

Comment: Did you check server logs to find out the problem?

Comment: I checked Symfony logs, they didn't mention anything. I'll try looking at server logs, I'm not sure I tried that. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I meant server logs, not Symfony's. Apache logs for example.

Comment: I use a shared server and don't have access to Apache error logs. The only server logs I can find are access logs I found in a /logs directory on my FTP. They only display things such as : 88.170.xx.xx - - [28/Sep/2013:19:21:25 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 609 www.mywebsite.com "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.76 Safari/537.36" "-"

Comment: OK, I "solved" the problem by reinstalling my bundles on the latest version of Symfony and it works just fine. It seems to me the 2.2.1 has some settings my server didn't like.